# Read URL parameters in LWC salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

I am using lightning navigation to pass `recordId` from the parent component to the child component.

On button click, I am navigating to child component like below URL -

https://XXXXXXXXXX.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/c__ChildComp?c__recordId=t2B9E000123JvDJUA0

I need to get the `recordId` from the URL in the child component and pass it to apex methods.

I tried the below, but did not get the `recordId`.

```
  import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from "lwc";
    import { getRecord, generateRecordInputForUpdate } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
    import { CurrentPageReference } from "lightning/navigation";
    
    export default class TestLWC extends LightningElement {
     @track getrecordId;
      @wire(CurrentPageReference)
      currentPageReference;
     setCurrentPageReference(currentPageReference) {
    this.currentPageReference = currentPageReference;
  }
      getrecordId =
        this.currentPageReference && this.currentPageReference.state.c__recordId
    
    @wire(getData, { getrecordId: "$getrecordId" })
    
    }
```

Comment: Looking at the docs, seems you will need to *inject* the current page reference using a setter function. Can you try that out?

Comment: like this i need to set? set setrecordId(){
       this.currentPageReference && this.currentPageReference.state.c__recordId;
    }

Comment: Like this `setCurrentPageReference(currentPageReference) {this.currentPageReference = currentPageReference; .....}`

Comment: I have written the code as above. Still i am not getting the value.. have i written it wrongly?

Answer (score 4):

You can get recordId based on below code using CurrentPageReference object.  This will return record id from parent object.

```
You can get recordId based on below code.  

import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { LightningElement ,wire,track} from 'lwc';
export default class TestLWC {

    @track recordId='';
     @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    currentPageReference; 

    get recordIdFromState(){
        return this.currentPageReference &&
            this.currentPageReference.state.c__recordId; 
    }
    renderedCallback()
    {
      if(this.recordId==='')
      {
          this.recordId=this.recordIdFromState;
          console.log(this.recordId);
          //call apex after this.recordId has value
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dhanik.. I am using @wire service to call apex..@wire(getData, { parentId: "$recordId" })  Datadetails;.. can i use directly this.recordId instead of "$recordId"

Comment: Yes. We can. Parameter with $ to indicate that it’s dynamic and reactive. It references a property of the component instance. If its value changes, the template rerenders.

Comment: Hi Dhanik.. thanks for the help. i got the recordId . One doubt. can we use setter for setting the recordId from currentPageReference ? instead of renderedCallback()

Comment: Yes. Try with this. async connectedCallback() {
        this.recordId = this.currentPageReference.state.c__recordId;}

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get parameters from URL is use **CurrentPageReference**.

`currentPageReference.state` allows you to get params.

Example:

```js
    import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
    import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
    
    export default class Test extends LightningElement {
    
        recordId = null;

        @wire(CurrentPageReference)
        getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
           if (currentPageReference) {
              this.urlStateParameters = currentPageReference?.state?.c__recordId;
           }
        }
    }
```

More details you can find here
https://beyondthecloud.dev/blog/get-url-parameters-in-lwc